# Adding an in-proc COM Server object to a C# application

Tags: c#, c++, com

I am new to COM and need to add a Server COM object to my c# application so I can call its methods and implement events.  The documentation I have says this requires a COM-aware language such as Visual C++.  My app is written in C# so I'm not sure how this is going to work.  Any direction would be appreciated.

I am writing an app that communicates with a serial hypercom terminal.  The device came with a DLL (the com server interface) that I will need to figure out how to use in my c# application.

I added a reference to the DLL to my project, which shows up as a type library.  In object explorer I get interfaces, and some classes etc.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the COM object as a reference.  .NET will create an interop assembly to work with the COM object, just like it was a .NET type.

Comment: Thanks, I added a reference to the DLL to my project, which shows up as a type library. In object explorer I get interfaces, and some classes etc.  Now I just don't know how to use them really since the only sample code I have is in C++ and uses a class that inherits from CComObjectRoot.

Comment: @pkan522: You should have some objects you can instantiate in that library (which implement the interface(s) you need).  Just construct them like any other .NET object.

Answer (score 0):

1. [CComObjectRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a05f3yh8(VS.80).aspx1.) can be used as a base class for all COM objects implemented with ATL. As such you don't have to worry to implement something similar in C#, the required methods (AddRef, Release, QueryInterface) will be generated by tlbexp for classes that are tagged with [ClassInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fcadw4a(VS.71).aspx).
2. STDMETHODIMP is a define which serves to declare the most common methods that can be called from COM (#define STDMETHODIMP HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE). Again if your class is tagged with ClassInterface you will not have to worry about.
3. Such construction is required in C++ when your class implements several interfaces. I think this is not required if you tell C# compiler that your C# object implement IDispatch, IFPESOlementationEvents. The appropriate code will be written automatically by the compiler.

Probably everything will not make much sense if you are new to COM and C#, I'll suggest to take a look at the various introduction that you may find on the web, like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/cominterop.aspx).